# The composition of two unbounded linear operator is also unbounded or not?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and consider some linear operators $ A, B: H\rightarrow H $. In functional analysis, I knew that if $A$ and $B$ are both bounded, then the composition $AB$ is bounded.

I'm curious about the situation when $A$ and $B$ are unbounded and linear. Now, is $AB$ also unbounded or not? I tried to prove it or find a counterexample to show it's wrong, but I failed. Could someone give me a hand?

I've found an example, but not in Hilbert space:

$H=l^\infty,\|x\|=\max_n{x_n}$

Let $a=(1,1,1/2,2,1/3,3,\cdots), Ax=(a_nx_n)_{n=1}^\infty$

and $b=(1,1,2,1/2,3,1/3,\cdots), Bx=(b_nx_n)_{n=1}^\infty$

It seems that $AB=I$; hence, $AB$ is bounded, but both $A, B$ are unbounded.

Am I right? Are there any examples in Hilbert space?

Comment: Those examples are not well-defined on $H = \ell^\infty$, as certain bounded sequences will not map to a bounded sequence in $H$, e.g. $x = (1, 1, 1, \ldots)$.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, AB in my example is not well-defined.

Comment: @TheoBendit surely the domain is not the full $\ell^\infty$ but that's to be expected given that those operators are unbounded. Am I missing something?

Comment: @lcv Usually, in practice unbounded operators mean unbounded closed operators that are densely defined. Of course, in that case the domain cannot be the entire space (insofar as the space is a Banach space) by closed graph theorem. But without the assumption of closedness you can have an unbounded operator which is everywhere defined, as MaoWao's answer demonstrated.

Comment: @DavidGao Thanks for the clarification, but that wasn't the case in the OP example, hence my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The composition $AB$ can be bounded even if $A$ and $B$ are unbounded. Let $H$ be an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space with normalized Hamel basis $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ and let $\phi\colon \mathbb N\to I$ be an injection. Define
\begin{align*}
A e_i&=\begin{cases}ne_i&\text{if }i=\phi(n),\,n\text{ even},\\0&\text{otherwise},\end{cases}\\
B e_i&=\begin{cases}n e_i&\text{if }i=\phi(n),\,n\text{ odd},\\0&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}
\end{align*}
As $\lim_{n\to \infty}\lVert A e_{\phi(2n)}\rVert=\lim_{n\to\infty} \lVert B e_{\phi(2n+1)}\rVert=\infty$, both $A$ and $B$ are unbounded. However, $AB=0$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful response!

Answer (score 0):

MaoWao's answer provides an example where you require the domain to actually be the entirety of $H$, which matches your question description. However, unbounded operators in practice usually mean something else, namely unbounded closed operators that are defined on a dense subspace (where closed means the graph of the operator is closed in $H \times H$). Such an operator can never be defined on the entirety of $H$ (or any Banach space, for that matter) due to closed graph theorem. If that is what you want instead, the following is an example: $A$ is multiplication by $x$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $B$ is multiplication by $1/x$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Then $AB$ is the identity operator. (More precisely, the closure of $AB$ is the identity operator. $AB$ itself is only densely defined.)

Comment: Thanks! I get it!